# Javax.persistance not available in TomEE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, classnotfoundexception

When running my Java EE app on TomEE I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery

There are no compile time errors when I build the app.I am developing in Eclipse and have *Apache TomEE* selected under *targeted runtimes* in the project properties, so that the project has access to Java EE.

As the project uses Hibernate I have the following jars in the WEB-INF\lib directory (it's my understanding that these jars in turn use javax.persistence):

- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4
- hibernate-core-4.3.5
- hibernate-jpa-2.1

I've seen a bunch of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081631/what-hibernate-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-persist) detailing that the solution is to add the required JPA jar into the lib directory of the app and all will be well. But although that solution may work it sounds hacky to me, I want TomEE to manage the JPA libraries itself. It's a Java EE server so why doesn't it do this. Whats a clean solution?

Comment: This class exists since JPA 2.1. I guess your TomEE version only supports JPA 2.0. And indeed, thehome page of TomEE says: "Java EE 6 Web Profile". Java EE 6 includes JPA 2.0, not 2.1.

Comment: Got a similar setup and I have the warning on TOMEE boot: ... WARN- jar '/<myproject>/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored. Any idea on how to overcome this? Switch to TOMEE-2.0.0.SNAPSHOT maybe?

Comment: @Continuity8 - it seems hacky to me as well to solve this issue by dropping jars into a production env TOMEE. Moreover, it does not work in developer setups where maven is used for integration tests for example... :-/ Anyone got a "clean way" idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@JB Nizet**'s answer is the accepted solution:

> This class exists since JPA 2.1. I guess your TomEE version only
>   supports JPA 2.0. And indeed, thehome page of TomEE says: "Java EE 6
>   Web Profile". Java EE 6 includes JPA 2.0, not 2.1. –  JB Nizet

Comment: You have to add the jar yourself, or use a container that supports JPA 2.1 by default.

Comment: thanks, i've changed hibernate version to 4.2 which is compliant with jpa 2.0. Thank you and @JB Nizet)